# Error - "Not authorized to send apple events to Microsoft word" from applescript

Tags: ms-word, applescript, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.mac

I want to access "Microsoft word" from AppleScript but while executing the AppleScript from visual studio for macOs Catalina (version - 10.15) it gives error "Not authorised to send apple events to Microsoft word". AppleScript works from script editor but not from visual studio. I have explored a lot find some solutions like
Goto Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Automation -> Privacy tab and check the "Microsoft Word" checkbox under Visual studio.

But on my machines privacy tab Microsoft Word is not available under Visual studio. So how we can add "Microsoft word" under "Visual Studio" in Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Automation -> Privacy tab. or how we can deal with the error "Not authorised to send apple events to Microsoft word".
Your help will be most appreciated.

Looking forward your response.

Thanks,
Pooja.

Comment: The you|enduser has to manually enable it under the macOS Setting

Comment: But how can i do that even app not prompts for microsoft word permission.

Comment: And also there is no entry of app in automation of privacy tab.

Comment: Solved issue - it is worked in release mode but not debug mode and i was tried it in debug mode.But why it is not worked in debug mode.